# Show pairing notification from android app

Tags: android

I have a simple Bluetooth app on android that connects to a device using RFCOMM.  On the first connection, the device needs to be paired.  Android does this by adding a "Bluetooth pairing request" notification which the user then needs to click on by first pulling down the notification area.

I know this is "standard" Android behaviour, but is there any way to get it to either:

a) Automatically expand the notification area

or

b) (Preferred) Actually bring the pairing notification to the front

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also had a problem with this.  I can give you one way to bring the notification to the front but it's not pretty.  If you run the connection request (BluetoothSocket.connect()) on the UI thread the pairing pin dialog will come to the foreground.  However your user experience will suffer for doing this.  Google really need to expose an intent for this so that security is maintained but developers can explicitly request pairing with a particular device.